# Rails Self referential has_many through self

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So I have a self referential rails model. In this model, a user has many friends, and all users have statuses. I would like for users to be able to get the statuses of other users. But I run into stack overflow errors because of recursive method calls.

```
class User
  has_many :statuses

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships

end
```

I want to be able to say

```
class User
  has_many :statuses

  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :friend_statuses, :through => :friends, :class_name => :statuses
end
```

however, this obviously creates a recursive call, which leads to SO. Is there any way I can get all of the friends statuses in a semantic, RESTful manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a method in your user model like this

```
def friends_statuses
  Status.where(user_id: friends.pluck(:id))
end
```

Not quite the way you wanted to do it, but I think it'd work.

Answer (score 1):

Is creating association is mandatory? I think, you can fetch the friends' status in the  controller itself. Something like:

```
@user = User.find(some_id_here)
@friends = @user.friends.includes(:statuses)
```

and then you can just iterate through @friends to get the status as:

```
@friends.each do |friend|
  friend.status.each do |status|
    #do something with friend and status
  end
end
```

Hope it makes sense to you!

Comment: Ya, I was trying to avoid extraneous methods and iteration. But I think I'll have to do that.

Comment: whatever method you use, you'll have to iterate to through friends to get his statuses. The only thing you can do is reduce the number of queries, thats what my example is doing.